# Crystal Reports, Command statement, and SQL Server 2008 with variables

Tags: sql-server, parameters, crystal-reports, command

I have a rather involved Command statement that I am passing through Crystal Reports 2013 (CR) to SQL Server 2008.  There are several static parameters which I created in CR that are static but allow for multiple values.  The way I would like these parameters to be work would be for the end user to either select "NA" if they do not want to search using that particular criteria or if they do want to search for this particular criteria, then they would input the values.  One example is searching by medication.  If the end user wants to find patients prescribed who have been prescribed metformin, predisone, or albuteral in the last year, they would input those three names into the parameter field.  If the end user did not want to search for specific medications, then they would type in "NA".

To accommodate this type of use, I declared variables in my Command statement and wanted to do something along the lines of the following:

```
DECLARE @IncludeRx  VARCHAR(254)
DECLARE @HasRx INTEGER
BEGIN SET @IncludeRx = {?MedicationNames} END
IF @IncludeRx = 'NA'
BEGIN SET @HasRx = 0 END
IF @IncludeRx <> 'NA'
BEGIN SET @HasRx = 1 END
```

The subsequent queries would be like this:

```
IF @HasRx = 1
BEGIN
SELECT patient, medication_name, rx_date
FROM prescriptions
WHERE medication_name IN {?MedicationNames}
END
IF @HasRx = 0
BEGIN
SELECT patient, medication_name, rx_date
FROM prescriptions
END
```

If I only use one medication name, the query and everything works fine.  When I try to do two or more medication names, I get an error in Crystal Reports when I run it.

Is there any way to make this work?  I can't really create the report in Crystal directly and the workaround I've found online to use a subreport will not work in this instance either.

Comment: How is the parameter string formatted?  In other words, what is the value for `@IncludeRx` in both the case where you pass in a single parameter and the case where you pass in two?

Comment: If you switch the `IN` query to be `SELECT TOP 1 patient, @IncludeRx AS medication_name, rx_date FROM prescriptions`, and rerun your query with a single parameter and again with more than one parameter, what results do you get?

Comment: When {?MedicationNames} is just one value, "metformin", @IncludeRx displays as just "metformin".  When {?MedicationNames} is more than one value, "metformin, gabapentin, albuterol", I end up with a failed to retrieve from the database in Crystal Reports - incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Interesting.  It sounds like Crystal is just slapping these values in as a raw string with no escaping involved.  I don't have a whole lot of experience with recent versions of Crystal, but this link (http://customerfx.com/pages/reporting/2009/12/08/using-multi-value-parameters-to-select-records-for-your-crystal-reports.aspx) has some good suggestions on using dynamic SQL and comma-delimited list parsing to achieve what you want to do.  Hope this helps!